# show 'loading' text/icon while external page gets loaded in phonegap, html5

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, same-origin-policy

In a phonegap-android application i want to open an external link within the application.

For this i used a plugin [childBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) and it works fine.

But the external link is taking time to load for which i want to ***show a wait/loading message.***

I also tried to open the external link through ajax-call, updating the div with the response page. and until reponse is not received i am showing a *loading message* but the problem with this approach is that page loses its styles and other structure.

I guess this is because i am putting entire external page inside the div tag which cannot render the entire page as the browser can do it.

Code snippet looks like-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage(url) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4){
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

How can i achieve this, can I override childBrowser?

Also

if i want to open the page in applications' web view then how can i achieve the same for web-view.

**EDIT**: *As per [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) one cannot call to a outside domain using xhr request. 
Okay understood. i checked in browser and got expected error: 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load'*

***But then how does it shows/opens the url in mobile?***

Ofcourse the page is not fully functional and thats my original issue.

i would post this as a separate question, but its related to my original question

Thanx.

Any hints/suggestions would be great.

Comment: A little confused by your issue and/or goal. Did you use openExternal or showWebPage, and which options, if any?

Comment: In the case of using openExternal() with usePhoneGap:true I'd expect to see a dialog, based on the underlying java. I was going to suggest that to you, if it suited your needs - but alas I don't see a dialog even in that case. Quite likely a phonegap bug.

Comment: jQuery Mobile includes a loading dialog/graphic, fully configurable, but your example is not using jQuery Mobile, so assuming that's not an option.

Comment: @Libby, thnx for your comments. though i need to find some other working solution.